# Open URL on right click with selected text in MS Teams

Tags: windows-10, contextmenu, microsoft-teams

Running Windows 10 & MS Teams

I am looking for a hack that will allow me to open a web site with the selected text concatenated to the end of the URL.

I work on a team and I get messages in MS Teams all the time asking me about ticket 23423. I would like to add a context menu in MS Teams that would allow me to select the ticket #, right click, select 'Open Ticket' & launch a preset URL.

So in the example above, the URL launched would be **http://TicketSystem.domain.com?ID=23423** in the default browser.

Note - I do not have access to any of the admin features of MS Teams.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to build an app for Teams that would let you do this, as a Message Extension - see here for more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/what-are-messaging-extensions?tabs=dotnet

I'm presuming, as you're asking this on Stack Overflow, that you have, or have access to, development skill to build something like this though.

Comment: I do have the development skill, but I am not an admin access to Teams

Comment: There was a time when the App Studio app inside Teams would let you side-load apps directly but I'm not sure if it still does that. You don't necessarily need admin access, but you might need an admin to install the app for you when you're done. I'd suggest dev'ing in a Development tenant (free from MS) till you're done, then have your admin side-load the app, just for your access. Not sure if that would work in your org scenario, depends on your relationship/access to admins...

Comment: Incidentally, there's a way to do it without dev and without admin access, but I think the input->output cycle would be annoyingly slow. Maybe it can give you an idea though - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/trigger-flow-teams-message